# Using prototype for KnockoutJS computed properties

Tags: knockout.js

Is it recommended to create computed properties on the prototype object?

This is what I've attempted below but the `firstName` binding is returning the function as a string rather than executing it (http://jsfiddle.net/W37Yh).

```
var HomeViewModel = function(config, $, undefined) {

    if (!this instanceof HomeViewModel) {
        return new HomeViewModel(config, $, undefined);
    }

    this.firstName = ko.observable(config.firstName);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(config.lastName);
};

HomeViewModel.prototype.fullName = function() {
    return ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};

var model = new HomeViewModel({
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith"
}, jQuery);

ko.applyBindings(model);​
```

Comment: No, prototype based object creation and knockout usually do not go well together.

Comment: I second what niko said, the problem with prototype is all instances of your objects are going to try to share the same computed on the prototype. Very bad.   The immediate thing you are seeing is the full name is just a function returning a computed, not a computed, thus the string.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`this` is not the Actual viewmodel since the instance is not created yet. You can do

```
ViewModel = function() {
   this.fullName = ko.computed(this.getFullName, this);
};

ViewModel.prototype = {
   getFullName: function() {
      return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This is also what was suggested by Ryan Niemeyer in [this video](http://vimeo.com/51103092)

Comment: Thanks. This approach also works for the subscribe as well. I've found that ViewModel.prototype.getFullName = function() {} is valid as well as your approach.

Comment: Yes, my prototype declaration is just a neat way of grouping all your prototype functions under one object literal